# Can we open a project module in a different window in IJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

After adding multiple projects as modules in an empty project in IJ, can I open each module in a different window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a new project for each module.

Comment: I can create a new project, but my ask is, is there a way to open module in a new window, if needed?

Comment: No, only a project have its own window. All you can do is e.g open File | Open | select pom.xml and select Open as Project.

Comment: Hope this feature will get integrated soon. Thanks

Comment: @TechPassionate Well, did you report it?

Comment: No, is there a channel where we can report it?

Comment: Thanks @Meo. Here is the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217315